# Reboot and Select proper Boot device error after trying to format an external hard drive (fedora)

Tags: fedora, disk, reboot, disk-image

I had an old laptop that had fedora 32 (or 33), but stopped working. Today I decided to open it and take the hard drive to use it as an external hard drive. I will call it `hard drive A`.

I connected `hard drive A` to my computer that runs fedora 33 (I installed fedora using a bootable USB flash drive) to format `hard drive A`. I followed [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-format-usb) tutorial, that uses the following commands:

```
df                         #to find the disk name
sudo umount /dev/sdc1      #to unmount the hard drive
sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdc1   #to format it
```

It took a little while to run `sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdc1`, but I figured it was fine because `hard drive A` was a 500 GB hard drive. I think the correct name for `hard drive A` was `/dev/sdc1`, but I am not 100% percent sure.

Then I ran the command:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdc1        #to confirm that formatting process was successful
```

which after a few seconds my screen froze and became unresponsive. (I was playing music in the background and the music kept playing).

I was able to connect remotely to the computer and everything seemed fine. Then I remotely ran the command `shutdown` to shut it down since the screen was unresponsive.

After it shut down, I disconnected `hard drive A` and pushed the power button to turn the computer back on. That is when I got the message: `Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key`.

I haven't done anything else (I am currently getting that message). Ideally, I can just fix this without having to reinstall the OS; but even if that is not possible, I need to recover the files that I had in my computer. I'd appreciate any help.

As for `hard drive A`, I currently don't care.

I asked this question before [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678539/reboot-and-select-proper-boot-device-fedora-error-after-formatting-a-disk), but it was very poorly worded because I was in freak out mode at the time I wrote it; while I am still in freak out mode, I think I can write more clearly now. I will delete the question I asked after some time.

Comment: as I suggested on your other question, *I would suggest booting with some live linux (maybe something like `systemrescue`) to investigatem and perhaps fix the boot issue (if you haven't clobbered the operating system of course)*

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reboot and Select proper Boot device fedora error after formatting a disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678539/reboot-and-select-proper-boot-device-fedora-error-after-formatting-a-disk)

Comment: don't repost the same question.  update your original question with any additional details. that's what the Edit link is for.

Comment: @cas As I said, I thought I just re write it from scratch. I'll delete the original.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have somehow managed to format drive in use for linux.

usually you would find out which drive the external drive is by typing

```
lsblk
```

which displays all drives (used and unused) then you would see the drive,

if you do just df - it only displays mounted drives, which is not always a good scenario if you have unformatted drive

but even better you could type

```
dmesg | tail
```

after you connect external disk

and in this log then you will see which device is attached - like /dev/sdb sdc sdd and depending of number of drivers you've got.

Since you formated /dev/sdc it does looks like you did formated external drive (presuming internal ones is /dev/sda or /dev/sdb, but other symptoms looks like first scenario

Things to try

boot from rescue disc from your distro or other live linux distro

then try to

```
lsblk
```

from resuce prompt and see which drives are available and which partitions

then try to mount those that do exist to see if you still have your data

```
mount /dev/sda1 /media
```

If you have it you could insert usb flash and copy important files to it..

of course to try to completely recover your system AFTER you make backup of important data it is best to follow some more in depth guide or just reinstall the system and then recover files from USB stick to which you have recovered your files in the first step.

Also tip while formatting NTFS drives - use -f argument which will do quick format and finish in seconds (rather then hours)

```
mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: How can I run commands? When I turn on the computer all I get is that message. I am not sure how to access a terminal (or something similar) from there.

Comment: Well if you have live usb stick ready, just boot from this usb stick and then type command, if you dont have live/rescue stick ready then you will have to use another computer to make rescue disk / live usb disk and then insert it into your computer and go from there. That is why you should always make rescue disk for your distro when you install your system. Also you could try to use disk with which you initially intalled the system in the first place. It should contain live  / rescue part

Comment: I can download live usb into a flash drive. Just to make sure, this is what you are talking about, right? https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-and-using-a-live-installation-image/

Comment: I did that. When I run ```mount /dev/sdb1 /media``` I get this error: ```mount: /media: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'```. I was trying to use the solution here https://askubuntu.com/questions/766048/mount-unknown-filesystem-type-lvm2-member but when I run ```vgrename <VG UUID> new_name``` I get the error that ```No such file or directory```. Do you know by any chance what to do in this case?

Comment: Good news - seems like your linux partition is not deleted, bad news, it will take much more steps to access it since they are on LVM partition, it would take too much to describe how to get to LVM partition, but try commands like pvscan and lvscan - also check out this link to find additional info - try googling, how to mount LVM partitions

LINK: https://cromwell-intl.com/open-source/lvm-rescue-boot.html

Comment: Here is article you need

https://ip-life.net/how-to-mount-lvm-partitions-from-rescue-mode-fedoracentosredhat/